# C# using a function to add values to a list

Tags: c#

Here's some context:
I am currently busy making a simple student administration for a school assignment. I am currently adding in the option to add students to a class. The code I use for that is this:

```
class Student
    {
        //alle properties van de student
        public string studentNumber { get; set; } //student number
        public string name { get; set; } //name of the student
        public string adress { get; set; } //adress of the student
        public string phoneNumber { get; set; } //phone number og the student

        //a constructor
        public Student(string studentNumber, string name, string adress, string phoneNumber)
        {
            this.studentNumber= studentNumber;
            this.name= name;
            this.adress= adress;
            this.phoneNumber= phoneNumber;
        }

        //To string override
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"studentNumber: {studentNumber}, name: {name}, adress: {adress}, phoneNumber:{phoneNumber}";
            //"aantal vakken: { String.Join(", ", vakken)}"
        }
```

this represent the personal info of a student. I created a list of students in the following class:

```
class Klas
{
    public string classCode{ get; set; }
    public string className{ get; set; }
    public List<Student> studentArray{ get; set; } //list with students

    public Klas(string klasnummer, string klasnaam, List<Student> studenten)
    {
        classCode= classCode;
        className= className;
        studentArray= studentArray;
    }
    static void AddStudents()
    {
        //this is where the students should be added to 'studentArray'
    }
}
```

Now I have laid the groundwork for the klassen a student can be put in, but I still ned to initialize those klassen:

```
class Program
{
    
    static List<Klas> ClassList= new List<Klas>();
    public static void AllClass()
    {
        //list with klassen and students 
        ClassList.Add(new Klas("KL0001", "AO1-A", new List<Student>()
             {
                
             }
        ));

        ClassList.Add(new Klas("KL0002", "AO1-B", new List<Student>()
             {
               //this is where I used to create the students on the spot
             }
       ));

        ClassList.Add(new Klas("KL0003", "AO2-A", new List<Student>()
             {

             }
        ));

        ClassList.Add(new Klas("KL0004", "GD3-C", new List<Student>()
             {

             }
        ));

        ClassList.Add(new Klas("KL0176", "STM4-P", new List<Student>()
             {

             }
        ));
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
                   
    }

}
```

This class posesses several klassen that the students need to be put into (or not as a student doesn't have to be in a klas). The problem is that I am not allowed to simply add the students within those klassen using `new student("studentnummer", "naam", "all the other variabels you can see inside of the Student class")` and I have to use a seperate function(`Voegstudenttoe()`) to add them instead.

And if you think thats already a lot, the students have to already exist before I can add them to a list since certain students might not be in a klas and just go through school on their own.

This has all culminated into me not having a clue on what to do as my tiny brain fails to comprehend something like this. In other words: I need help.

Comment: it all comes down to me wanting to add students to a list using a seperate funcion

Comment: Not sure if I have understood you correctly but it sounds like you want to use a factory to create the students and then add them. The factory design pattern would suit this. https://garywoodfine.com/factory-method-design-pattern/

Comment: Notes: 1. name of properties convention for .NET, CLS compliance... Use 'CamelCase'' for your properties. eg: instead of 'studentnummer' use 'StudentNumber'. 2. Instead of 'class Klas' use: 'private class Klas'.

Comment: @BerBar I think it is "camelCase" versus "PascalCase" - but you are right, the convention is to write StudentNumber

Comment: @HansKeﬆing i think we can call UpperCamelCase :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That method

```
static void Voegstudenttoe()
{
    //this is where the students should be added to a klas inside the klassenlist
}
```

should not be static, so you can add a Student to this particular instance of a Klas.

Next, you should pass the student-to-add as parameter. Then you can easily add it to your list:

```
public void Voegstudenttoe(Student newStudent)
{
   if (newStudent != null)
       this.Studentenlijst.Add(newStudent);
}
```

by the way, that Studentenlijst property can also be:

```
public List<Student> Studentenlijst { get; } = new List<Student>();
```

this way no-one can replace the list and you are sure that there *is* a list (not null).

(added after comments) That not-null guarantee assumes of course that you don't replace the list in the constructor (with possibly a null value). Either remove that parameter or add every student of the provided list (please do a null check) to the existing internal list.

Comment: Actually if someone passes `null` as `List<Student>` to the `Klas` constructor the list will be `null` so the guarantee that you can be sure there is a list is not correct in my opinion.

Comment: Yes, that should be removed from the constructor, or add every supplied student to the existing list, instead of replacing it.

Comment: I agree with that, however that is not part of you answer, while the claim that you can be sure that there is a list (not null) is.